# Inserting link (from cell) as image in email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create an email for customers and embed an image that is linked to a site. The link will be different for each customer, but the link will always appear in the same cell (AH7).
The image is saved in "C:\Fake Folder\Fake SubFolder\image.png". I can upload the image online if it makes it easier/will be displayed consistently.

I can find bits and pieces of information but nothing that works all together.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim xStrBody As String
    xStrBody = "Hi" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") _
      & "Please Click" & "<a href=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range(AH7) ">C:\Fake Folder\Fake SubFolder\image.png" "Thank you" & "<br>" _
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(J1)
        .Subject = "Test Email"
        .HTMLBody = .HTLMBody & xStrBody
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use html in the right way

```
Function FileNameFromPath(strFullPath As String) As String    
    FileNameFromPath = Right(strFullPath, Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "\"))     
End Function

Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_test()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim imageFile As String
imageFile = "C:\Fake Folder\Fake SubFolder\image.png"

Dim fileName As String
fileName = FileNameFromPath(imageFile)

Dim xStrBody As Variant
    xStrBody = "<html><p>Hi " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value _
          & "Please Click </p>" & "<a href=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH7").Hyperlinks(1).Address _
          & "<img src=""" & fileName & """ height=520 width=750></a>" _
          & "<p>Thank you" & "<br></p>"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").Value
    .Subject = "Test Email"
    .attachments.Add imageFile, 1, 0
    .htmlBody = xStrBody
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you have the hyperlink address directly in cell AH7 you need to use `.value` instead of `.Hyperlinks(1).Address` for `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH7").Hyperlinks(1).Address`. I also assumed that you several times did not add the quotes in the code of your original post.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, however it's telling me Run time error 424 Object required.
I've changed to the correct file path and referenced it in fileName and imgFile.

Comment: You need to be mor specific! At which line do you get the RTE 424? Be aware the fake file should be a real file now! I also said you might need to replace `.Hyperlinks(1).Address` with`.value`.

Comment: I've fixed that part up I think, the below isn't working unfortunately ↓.

Comment: I am afraid but your feedback is not useful at all. I tested the code I posted and it is working for me. I specifically asked at which line you get the RTE! It had been really nice if you had answered that.

Comment: I feel so dumb, I've retried and it works like an absolute charm. Thank you so much for hanging in there with me, and even putting the whole code in here for me. You're an absolute legend.